# NetSuite - how to assign multiple roles to a contact

Tags: netsuite

I need to be able to assign multiple roles to the contact, not just the only one. Right now I'm using next code to set role to the contact:

```
            //get the internal ID of created contact
            var contactInternalId = ((RecordRef) response.baseRef).internalId;

            //set roles
            var attachContact = new AttachContactReference();
            attachContact.attachTo = new RecordRef
                {
                    type = RecordType.customer,
                    typeSpecified = true,
                    internalId = customerId
                };
            attachContact.contact = new RecordRef {internalId = contactInternalId};
            attachContact.contactRole = new RecordRef {internalId = role};

            var resp = _service.attach(attachContact);
```

I see no way to set multiple roles to a contact (unlike the permissions, where I could use the MultiSeceltCustomFieldRef).

I tried to search the internet, but it is not much info out there.

I would appreciate any help, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can call attach multiple times to assign multiple roles.

Comment: No, this is not working. It just sets the latest provided role.